# International Baccalaureate - where to find the detail of the math programs?

Tags: secondary-education, middle-school

Does anyone know what is the exact program of the International Baccalaureate in math?

I've been looking for the MYP and DP programs in the website of the International Baccalaureate Institute but could not find any detailed program.

Thank you in advance!

Edit: I realize one cannot access these documents unless you are a teacher in an IB school. However, can anyone tell me if there are Markov chains, as well as number theory (Fermat's theorem) in these programs ?

Comment: I have always been disappointed with the lack of transparency for the IB mathematics curriculum. I often come back to this when dealing with placement for students coming from high school to college.

Comment: The IBO has gotten stricter about controlling access to subject guides, past papers, and other documents. They've really tried to crack down on resource sharing, for example on Reddit. It's too bad that new links keep popping up all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 2024, Mathematics: Applications and Interpretation does cover Markov chains, but at the higher level only, not at the standard level. It is listed in the syllabus under subtopic AHL 4.19. Mathematics: Analysis and Approaches does not cover Markov chains at the standard level or at the higher level.

Neither of the two mathematics courses currently offered in the IB Diploma Programme cover number theory. Prior to 2021, there was some number theory, up to Fermat's little theorem. It was a part of the discrete math topic, which was an option topic for Mathematics HL and a required topic for Further Mathematics HL.